# Why is OpenAI's evolution strategy a natural evolution strategy?

Tags: gradient, evolutionary-algorithms

Natural Evolution Strategies follow the natural gradient using the Fisher Information Matrix $\mathbf{F}_\theta$ of a search distribtion $p_\theta$. That is, parameters in [natural evolution strategies](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/wierstra14a/wierstra14a.pdf) are updated with:

\begin{equation}
 \theta \gets \theta + \alpha \mathbf{F}^{-1} \nabla_\theta J
\end{equation}

with

\begin{align}
 \nabla_\theta J =& \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \nabla_\theta p_\theta(x_i)\\
\mathbf{F} = & \frac{1}{n}\nabla_\theta\log p_\theta(x_i) \nabla_\theta\log p_\theta(x_i)^\top
\end{align}

where $x_i$ is a drawn sample from $p_\theta(.)$ and $f(x_i)$ is its fitness.

In [OpenAI's evolution strategy approach](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03864) the update looks like this:

\begin{equation}
 \theta \gets \theta + \alpha \nabla_\theta J
\end{equation}

with

\begin{equation}
\nabla_\theta J = \frac{1}{n \sigma} \sum_{i=1}^n f(\theta + \sigma \epsilon_i) \epsilon_i
\end{equation}

I do not quite understand, why the latter is a natural evolution strategy, i.e., follow the natural gradient, as the authors claim.

Comment: Did you end up coming up with an explanation to your question?

Comment: It boils down to usage of ${\it natural gradient}$, Amari's definition used KL distance and the first paper you mentioned used Fisher's matrix. It is about accounting for uncertainty in second order updates.In OpenAI's approach using $\sigma$, noise standard-deviation accounts for the uncertainty, so it makes the apprach natural evaluation strategy.

Comment: @msuzen I don't think that's correct as stated. Yes, the natural gradient may be about accounting for uncertainty, but it is about accounting for it in a very particular way. Not any constant factor depending on the standard-deviation makes the method a NES. In contrast to the update rule used by OpenAI, using the Fisher information would give you a sigma in the numerator and not in the denominator.

Comment: @s1624210 Yes, you are right. It looks like there might be some intricacies and deeper insights there. Though, the natural gradient is indeed about accounting for uncertainty.